# Concurrently drop an unique constraint in PostgresQL?

Tags: postgresql

We have this large table in our Postgres DB, let's call it `DataTable` with a decent amount of read/write operations.

There currently exists a **unique** constraint on this table that I would like to get rid of and instead replace it with a different unique constraint. I see that we can reduce the downtime of the table for index creation by using `CONCURRENTLY` for index creation/deletion but is there a similar way to simulate `DROP CONSTRAINT CONCURRENTLY` for a unique index?

If not, how can I remove this constraint safely?

Comment: There is no direct equivalent to `DROP CONSTRAINT CONCURRENTLY` in PostgreSQL.
The only way to achieve what you are asking for is by minimizing the downtime by creating first the new constraint then dropping the old one

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for a `CONCURRENTLY` clause when dropping a constraint, because that operation is always very fast.

If you experience something else, that is because you have long running transactions on that table. Such transactions will block the `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock that `ALTER TABLE` needs on the table for a very short time. You will have to find a point in time when there is no long running transaction using the table.

To avoid problems caused by waiting for a lock, use a technique like this:

```
SET lock_timeout = '1s';
ALTER TABLE tab DROP CONSTRAINT myconstr;
```

If the statement is blocked for more than a second, it will terminate wiht an error. Keep repeating that until it succeeds.

Comment: If dropping a constraint (and implicitly dropping the underlying unique index) is a quick operation, is it a safe assumption that dropping any index should be a quick operation?

I see that we can use `DROP INDEX CONCURRENTLY`, but if it's always a quick operation I can't see when we would use this CONCURRENTLY keyword.

Comment: `DROP INDEX CONCURRENTLY` isn't there because the operation is slow, but it waits in the background until it finds a slot where the table is not locked. It is just a more convenient way of doing what I suggested in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL, you cannot use DROP CONSTRAINT CONCURRENTLY. You can achieve what you want in two steps:

1. Create a new Constraint, and Alter the table to add that constraint.
2. Drop the already implemented Unique constraint.

If you don't know the name of an already implemented UNIQUE constraint, you can get its auto-generated name through pg admin.